# How do i fix "Job was Cancelled" exception?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

In my Fragment, I'm trying to fetch data from Firebase Database using coroutines where data is retrieving properly. Here is my code

```
 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi    //Fragment Class code
  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    checkOutViewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
        try{
            if (isActive){
                checkOutViewModel.getCartDataFromFirebaseNetwork().collect{
                    tempList.add(it)
                }
            }
        }catch (ex : Exception){
            Log.d("exception message",ex.cause?.message!!)  //Fatal Exception: Main
        }
        orderListAdapter?.submitList(tempList)
        binding.progress.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.recycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}

 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi        //Viewmodel class code
   suspend  fun getCartDataFromFirebaseNetwork()= firebaseNetwork.getCartFromFirebase()

 


 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi      //Repository class code
   suspend fun getCartFromFirebase() = callbackFlow<Cart> {
        ensureActive()
        val counterList = myFlow.toList()
        val itemList = myFlow.mapBasketToItemsList().toList()
        val pairs = myFlow.mapBasketListToQuantity().toList()
        if(itemList.isNotEmpty() && pairs.isNotEmpty()){
            for ((current,item) in itemList.withIndex()) {
                val cart = Cart(counterList[current].basketId!!,item.id!!,item.url!!,item.name!!,pairs[current].first,pairs[current].second,counterList[current].itemCounter!!,pairs[current].second)
                offer(cart)
            }
            channel.close()
        }
}

  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
 val myFlow = callbackFlow<Basket> {
    databaseReference.child("Cart").child(getCurrentUserUid())
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val basket = Basket()
                        basket.basketId = data.key
                        basket.itemId = data.child("itemId").value as String
                        basket.itemCounter = data.child("itemCounter").value as String
                        basket.itemWeight = data.child("itemWeight").value as String
                            offer(basket)
                    }
                    channel.close()
                }
            }
        })
    awaitClose()
}

  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
  private  fun Flow<Basket>.mapBasketToItemsList() : Flow<Items>  = map{basket ->
         suspendCoroutine<Items> {continuation ->
             databaseReference.child("Items").child(basket.itemId!!)
                 .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                     override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                     }
                     override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                         if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                           val   items = dataSnapshot.getValue(Items::class.java)!!
                             continuation.resume(items)
                         }
                     }
                 })
         }
}

 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
  private fun Flow<Basket>.mapBasketListToQuantity() : Flow<Pair<String,String>> = map{basket ->
    suspendCoroutine<Pair<String,String>> {continuation ->
        databaseReference.child("Quantities").child(basket.itemId!!)
            .child(basket.itemWeight!!)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                }
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        val key = dataSnapshot.key
                        val value = dataSnapshot.value as String
                        val myPair = Pair(key!!, value)
                        continuation.resume(myPair)
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

**Edited:
This is my Navigation Flow of Fragments**

**OnBoarding-Authentication-MainFragment-CheckItemListFragment**

```
 override fun onStart() {  //OnBoarding Fragment
    super.onStart()
    try {
        if(viewModel.checkAuth()){
            updateUI()
        }
    }catch (ex : Exception){
        println("In onBoarding Fragment")
        Log.d("exception message",ex.cause?.message!!)
    }
}

override fun onStart() {  //Authentication Fragment
    super.onStart()
    try {
        if(mAuth.currentUser == null){
            showShortToast("Please Login")
        }else{
            updateUI()
        }
    }catch (ex : Exception){
        println("In authentication Fragment")
        Log.d("exception message",ex.cause?.message!!)
    }
}

 override fun onStart() {  //MainFragment
    super.onStart()
    try {
        if(mainFragmentViewModel.checkSignIn() == null)
            findNavController().navigateUp()
        binding.toolbar.add_to_cart.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_checkoutItemsList)
        }
    }catch (ex : Exception){
        println("In Main Fragment")
        Log.d("exception",ex.message!!)
    }
}

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
override fun onStart() {  //CheckItemList Fragment
    super.onStart()
    try {
        binding.addToCart.setOnClickListener {
            checkOutViewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                val message = orderListAdapter?.getList()?.let { it1 -> checkOutViewModel.submitFinalCart(it1) }
                if(message!!){
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_checkoutItemsList_to_finalCarts)
                }
            }
        }
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            ensureActive()
            checkOutViewModel.getCartDataFromFirebaseNetwork().collect {
                tempList.add(it)
                orderListAdapter?.submitList(tempList)
                binding.progress.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.recycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }catch (ex : Exception){
        println("In checkItemList Fragment")
        Log.d("exception message",ex.cause?.message!!)
    }
}
```

**Edited** : My Logcat is :-

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-10 21:18:40.605 30715-30715/com.example.groceryapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.groceryapp, PID: 30715
f.d
    at com.example.groceryapp.checkout.CheckoutItemsList$e.a(:73)
    at f.z.k.a.a.b(:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.u0.run(:334)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.z0.k(:68)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.r0.b(:354)
    at f.z.i.b(:42)
    at com.example.groceryapp.f.a$r$a$b.a(:262)
    at com.google.firebase.database.m$a.a(:179)
    at com.google.firebase.database.u.a0.a(:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.u.i0.d.a(:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.u.i0.g$a.run(:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

This is how i used my **Try Catch** block in every Fragments to handle this issue but it is also not working at all. I'm also using **isActive** method to check whether the job is still active or not before retrieving any data. I get "**Fatal Exception: Main, Job was Cancelled**" if i pressed back button before recyclerview shows the data. This exception only comes if i use callback flow. Is there any way to handle this issue or is it a bug in callback flow?. So far I couldn't find any possible answer that will solve my issue. Please tell me how do i fix it?

Comment: If user pressed back before the fetching process finished, then it will throw what you stated, Job was cancelled. That is because your current fragment is destroyed. Also your code seems to have handled it with `Try Catch`. Can you explain more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes you got it correct. I got the exception when I pressed back button while retrieving data from firebase database.  I wanna handle this exception so that my app should not crash. Can you tell me how should I do it?

Comment: Try to wrap all your code inside `onStart` lifecycle with `Try Catch`.

Comment: you mean me to wrap also previous class onStart method with **Try catch** where i'm navigating this fragment so that the exception will bounce back to the previous fragment and will handle there? Right

Comment: hmm, what I mean is wrap all line below `super.onStart()` in your fragment class. On the fragment you are showing above.

Comment: @FranzAndel No it is also not working. I've tried as what you said but that also not working.

Comment: @FranzAndel I edited my question with some  code to show you how i used Try catch block in Fragments as you said but that also not working.

Comment: wow, looks like the `Try Catch` is not the main issue here.
Try chaning `checkOutViewModel.viewModelScope.launch` to `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch`. If the issue still persists, please share the logcat so it can help us.

Comment: Actually I did that too but nothing changes. I'll share you  the logcat

Comment: @FranzAndel I get this exception kotlinx.coroutines.n1: Job was cancelled; job=f2{Cancelled}@7f2f1e8.

Comment: sorry, could you please share the full logcat by editing your question? so it will help me & others in tracing the issue

Comment: @FranzAndel I edited my question with the logcat. You can check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with the same issue before and here is my solution with an extension of SendChannel

```
fun <T> SendChannel<T>.offerCatching(element: T): Boolean {
     return runCatching { offer(element) }.getOrDefault(false)
}
```

and when emit event just call offerCatching

Answer (score 0):

Why you launch coroutine in fragment `onStart` with `viewModelScope` ?
in fragment/activity you should use `lifecycleScope`.
see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) for more details.

Comment: Okay I'll use it and will let you know if the issue is still persist.

Comment: yes the  issue is still persist. it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `offer()` method into try..catch and capture `CancellationException`. You may create an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734114/how-to-spot-where-job-was-cancelled-exception-comes-from-when-all-your-corouti#comment115722020_60776251) function to use across the application where using `offer()` method.