# How can we achieve collectLatest behaviour using collect using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using `collectLatest` to collect the values from the flow but I am getting below exeception all the time whenever it process latest value and cancel the old processing value.

```
ChildCanceledException:  Child of the scoped flow was cancelled
```

Questions:

1. Can we avoid this exception using collectLatest?
2. Can we implement collect latest functionality using collect to avoid this exception?

Comment: Can you share an example that produces this error? `collectLatest` obviously isn't 100% broken or it wouldn't be in the library, so there must be something specific you're doing to produce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think for updation of your data variable you it should be flow where you can collect your data like this :-

**Declaration of variables**

```
private val _uiEvents = Channel<UIEvents>()
val uiEvents = _uiEvents.receiveAsFlow()
```

**Sending event or data to variable**

```
viewModelScope.lauch{
   _uiEvents.send(UIEvent())
}
```

**Collecting data**

```
viewModelScope.lauch{
  uiEvents.collect{ it: UIEvent ->
     /* Here will be your code to update you data and $it will be your updated value */
  }
}
```

Here uiEvents is collecting all new data from _uiEvents as flow and when you are using flow you can collect your data easily with couritin scope.

and this flow will be last long as your app so there are not option to for memory leak.

If you find this helpful than let me know if there are anything wrong with explanation then correct me I am happy to know your side answer. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with what the OP is asking about. It's just completely unrelated discussion of a possible way you can use Flows.

Comment: ohk I think I misunderstood question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was a [bug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1433#issuecomment-520388736), or maybe you [can't emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734114/how-to-spot-where-job-was-cancelled-exception-comes-from-when-all-your-corouti) after cancellation.

However, I am not able to reproduce the exception.

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val job = launch {
        val badFlow = flow {
            while (true) {
                emit(1)
                // yield()
            }
        }

        badFlow.collect {
            println("$it")
        }
    }
    delay(10)
    job.cancel()
}
```

```
1
1
1
1
1
...
```